# Creating an output File in java

Tags: java

So I have finished about 90% of this code, but I am stuck on the last part. So pretty much I want to store partNumber, quantity, and toalCost from my MainClass to my OrdersProcessed Class and make a outputfile. How do I go about doing that? Is that tutorial I posted with my code a good way to do that?

MainClass:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass
{

    private static final String DATA_FILE = "masterInventory.dat";
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        InventoryData myData;
        double price = 0.0;
        int quantity = 0;
        double totalCost = 0.0;
        int index = 0;
        int partNumber = 0;
        char runProgram;
        int totalFound;
        int partFound = 0;
        int partnotFound = 0;

        myData = new InventoryData(DATA_FILE);
        myData.loadArrays();
        myData.bubbleSort();

        System.out.println("Do you want to continue? prss 'Y' for yes or 'Q' to quit");
                runProgram = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
                runProgram = Character.toUpperCase(runProgram);


                while (runProgram == 'Y' || runProgram == 'Q')
                {

                    if(runProgram == 'Y')
                    {

                        System.out.print("Please enter your part number: "); 
                        partNumber = input.nextInt();

                        // TODO start your loop here

                        index = myData.binSearch(partNumber);

                        if(index != -1)
                        {
                            price = myData.getPrice(index);
                            System.out.printf("The price is %.2f%n", price);
                            System.out.print("How many would you like?");
                            quantity = input.nextInt();
                            totalCost = price * quantity;
                            partFound++;

                            // TODO do printing, writing to file here
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Part not found");
                            partnotFound++;
                        }

                        System.out.println("Part# ");
                        System.out.print(partNumber);
                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.println("Price $");
                        System.out.print(price);
                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.println("Quantity ");
                        System.out.print(quantity);
                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.println("totalPrice ");
                        System.out.print(totalCost);
                        System.out.println();

                        System.out.println("Do you want to continue? prss 'Y' for yes or 'Q' to quit");
                        runProgram = input.next().charAt(0);
                        runProgram = Character.toUpperCase(runProgram);

                    }
                    if (runProgram == 'Q')
                    {
                        totalFound = partFound + partnotFound;

                        System.out.println("Total parts found : " + partFound);
                        System.out.println("Total parts not found : " + partnotFound);
                        System.out.println("Total parts searched : " + totalFound);

                        break;
                    }// end if 'Q'
                }// end while
    }
}
```

OrderProcessed Class:

```
public class OrdersProcessed
{





    public OrdersProcessed(String File)
    {
        File = "ordersProcessed.dat";
    }


    public void saveOneRecord()
    {

    }
```

Then here is the tutorial I found:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String lastName, firstName;
    double salary;

    try
    {
        //Instantiate a PrintWriter to append to an existing file
        PrintWriter myPW = new PrintWriter (new FileWriter("employeeOut.dat", true));
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        //Input first value for lastName, which will be the LCV
        System.out.println("Input the employee's last name (or Q to quit): ");
        lastName = myScanner.nextLine();

        while (!(lastName.equals("Q") || lastName.equals("q")))
        {
            System.out.println("Input the employee's first name: ");
            firstName = myScanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Input the employee's salary: ");
            salary = myScanner.nextDouble();
            myScanner.nextLine();   //Eliminate carriage return left in stream after numeric input

            //Save one record
myPW.printf ("%s %s %.2f\n", lastName, firstName, salary);

            //Input next last name
            System.out.println("Input the employee's last name (or Q to quit): ");
            lastName = myScanner.nextLine();
        }//END while

        myPW.close();
        myScanner.close();

    }//END try
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}//END main method
```

Comment: Do you want to Serialize your OrdersProcessed class? Please check my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok at first I thought you wanted to store the partNumber, quantity and totalCost in a file and the code below should do it:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("file_name.txt", "UTF-8");
writer.println(partNumber);
writer.println(quantity);
writer.println(toalCost);
writer.close();
```

But it looks like you want to store the partNumber, quantity, and totalCost in the OrdersProcessed class and save it in a file.

So, first make your OrdersProcessed class implement Serializable:

```
public class OrdersProcessed implements Serializable {
```

Add the instance variables to OrdersProcessed class with setter methods:

```
int quantity = 0;
int partNumber = 0;
double totalCost = 0.0;
```

Add the following to your saveOneRecord method:

```
  try
  {
     FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ordersProcessed.dat");
     ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
     out.writeObject(e);
     out.close();
     fileOut.close();
  } catch(IOException e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Then add the following below your "// TODO do printing, writing to file here":

```
OrdersProcessed op = new OrdersProcessed();
op.setQuantity(quantity);
op.setPartNumber(partNumber);
op.setTotalCost(totalCost);
op.saveOneRecord();
```

More info about Serialization [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html).

Comment: He didn't specify the format he wants, the format ""%s %s %.2f\n" that you think he wants is from a tutorial that he found

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you have provided does indeed show a simple way of writing to a file.

As you can see, you'll need to create a PrintWriter object (making sure the file exists):

```
PrintWriter myPW = new PrintWriter (new FileWriter("employeeOut.dat", true));
```

Then you can use printf to print the multiple values on the same line.

```
myPW.printf ("%s %s %.2f\n", lastName, firstName, salary);
```

You can use this anywhere you want, as long as you have access to the print writer and the values you need. Above, the 3 values are lastName, firstName and salary, and these get added in place of the `%s` and `%.2f` bits in the first argument `"%s %s %.2f\n"` where `%s` means place the value as a string, and `%.2f` means place the value as a float to 2 decimal places. You can add as many as you want. See the Java Docs for further information regarding this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)

Finally, you'll have to close the PrintWriter object:

```
myPW.close();
```

You'll probably need to surround these operations with a try/catch statement looking for an IOException though.

Comment: Thats what I was looking at. What I got confused with is my saveOnRecord is suppose to store them in my ordersProcessed Class. So how does that work? Since im closing the file, im just assuming the saveOneRecord method will have to open it back to get those 3 values?

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, you want to store the data in the OrdersProcessed class during runtime? In that case, you would want to store the data in some sort of a List such as an ArrayList. In this case, perhaps create a class that takes the three items of data, and use a new instance of the object each time you store the data in the List. When you need to, you can loop through the List and write the data to file as above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with the way you did it, but I do see ways you can make your code a little cleaner. You didn't say you were having any errors, So I am assuming it works correctly.

I removed some unnecessary stuff from your code and tested it. It all works

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    String lastName = new String(), firstName;//Initialized lastName to prevent an error
    double salary;

    try
    {
        //Instantiate a PrintWriter to append to an existing file
        PrintWriter myPW = new PrintWriter (new FileWriter("employeeOut.dat", true));
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        //put all inputs inside the loop

        while (!(lastName.equals("Q") || lastName.equals("q")))
        {
            System.out.println("Input the employee's last name (or Q to quit): ");
            lastName = myScanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Input the employee's first name: ");
            firstName = myScanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Input the employee's salary: ");
            salary = myScanner.nextDouble();
            myScanner.nextLine();   //Eliminate carriage return left in stream after numeric input

            //Save one record
            myPW.printf ("%s %s %.2f\n", lastName, firstName, salary);

           //loops back to last name now

        }//END while

        myPW.close();
        myScanner.close();

    }//END try
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.print(ex);
    }
}//END main method

}
```